# Computing private key of a user from his RSA public key

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I know that we will give *(N,e)* as our public key to every one and *N* is product of two prime numbers *P* and *Q*. But I know that product of two prime numbers has only 4 divisors (1, itself, *P*, *Q*) and using a simple while loop hackers can easily get *P* and *Q* and compute *phi* also. And since they already know *E* they can easily determine *D* by using *E<sup>-1</sup> mod phi(N)* formula. So what am I missing?

Comment: Simple loop? What simple loop might that be?

Comment: I sugguest to move the question to Cryptography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the thing. If *p* and *q* are big, factoring *n* (calculating *p* and *q* out of it) is hard. It's also called the RSA problem. It is so hard that such a naive algorithm, as you've described it, would take many many years on an cluster to compute the private key out of the public key. Today, good starting values of *n* are typically 2048 or 4096-bit in size.

Let's take for example an *n* of 2048-bit. You need to check somewhere between *2<sup>1021</sup>* and *2<sup>1023</sup>* numbers on average to see if they are a factor. To do that you need to do at least one division per number with division being the costliest operation. Let's say you can do *2<sup>50</sup>* (this is already too optimistic) divisions per second. So it would take *2<sup>1021</sup>* * *2<sup>-50</sup>* = *2<sup>971</sup>* seconds to brute force it naively. Or that many years:

> 632876810481582893092457100785400357073646391563754928178128882051373633900610117258040958109029585581349076244353277284364674653853879268372390854352115493505836400606001292655231393152068425666747005563338382798494041874404131909211331579289714661817326517908344762063152744555537801

A better algorithm than what you described is the [general number field sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve). There are quantum algorithms that are supposed to run even faster.